# Testing if a lambda factory returns the correct result

Tags: java, lambda

I am writing a testcase for a factory class. The factory (rather a Prototype pattern) returns types of matchers according to the factory parameters. The matchers returned are static method references.

In the test, I found, that I cannot compare the resulting method references because I cannot access the initially created one. Since the context of the `::` operator decides if the method reference is recreated or reused, I stored the method references in `static finals`. The test will now compare the result against the statics:

```
    assertEquals(MatcherFactory.MATCH_A, matcherFactory.createMatcher(conditionA))
```

What I basically do, is storing the references to the wrapper classes of the lambdas. I see this approach valid. Is there anything wrong with this? Is there a hidden trap? The matchers are thread safe, of course.

Code sample:

```
public class MatcherFactory {

    public static final MyMatcher MATCH_FALSE = MatcherFactory::matchFalse;
    public static final MyMatcher MATCH_A = MatcherFactory::matchA;
    public static final MyMatcher MATCH_B = MatcherFactory::matchB;
    public static final MyMatcher MATCH_AB = MatcherFactory::matchAB;

    public MyMatcher getMatcherFor(Condition condition) {

        switch (condition) {
        case A:
            return MATCH_A;
        case B:
            return MATCH_B;
        case AB:
            return MATCH_AB;
        }

        return MATCH_FALSE;
    }

    public static boolean matchA(Object ... operators) {
    // match magic
    }

    public static boolean matchB(Object ... operators) {
    // match magic
    }

    public static boolean matchAB(Object ... operators) {
    // match magic
    }

    public static boolean matchFalse(Object ... operators) {
        return false;
    }
}
```